# How to run remote wss/http geth node?

Tags: ethereum, geth

I want to run my own remote node for my application.

Can I run a node that would be accessible via the wss and http protocol at the same time?

Something like this?

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "MY IP" --ws --wsaddr "MY IP" console
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. But it will not be wss (ws over TLS), it will be a plain web socket. You need a reverse proxy to secure the connection.